# How to embed for loops in Kotlin string templates

Tags: string, loops, templates, for-loop, kotlin

We can easily nest expression operators like `if` and `when` in Kotlin string templates:

```
"List ${if (list.isEmpty()) "is empty" else "has ${list.size} items"}."
```

But `for` or `while` are not expressions and can't be nested in template like this:

```
"<ol>${for (item in list) "<li>$item"}</ol>"
```

So I was looking for convinient ways to use loops inside large templates.

Comment: This question was also discussed at https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/template-engine/866

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest out-of-the-box way I found so far is to replace loops with equivalent [joinToString](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/join-to-string.html) calls:

```
"<ol>${list.joinToString("") { "<li>$it" }}</ol>"
```

or

```
"""
<ol>${list.indices.joinToString("") {
    """
    <li id="item${it + 1}">${list[it]}"""
}}
</ol>""".trimIndent()
```

In the matter of preference, it's also possible to simulate loops with helper functions:

```
inline fun <T> forEach(iterable: Iterable<T>, crossinline out: (v: T) -> String) 
    = iterable.joinToString("") { out(it) }

fun <T> forEachIndexed1(iterable: Iterable<T>, out: (i: Int, v: T) -> String): String {
    val sb = StringBuilder()
    iterable.forEachIndexed { i, it ->
        sb.append(out(i + 1, it))
    }
    return sb.toString()
}
```

and use them like this:

```
"<ol>${forEach(list) { "<li>$it" }}</ol>"
```

or

```
"""
<ol>${forEachIndexed1(list) { i, item ->
"""
    <li id="item$i">$item"""
}}
</ol>""".trimIndent()
```

Answer (score 4):

you can simply using `joinToString` instead.

```
val s = """<ol>
             ${list.joinToString { "<li>$it</li>" }}
           </ol>""";
```

### Output

```
<ol>
   <li>one</li>
   <li>two</li>
   ...
</ol>
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't get how it's different from the first code line in my answer. )

Comment: @Vadzim sir, I don't see your answer when I wrote mine. I found we are the same ...

Comment: No compaints then. But I was posting the question and the answer at once. Really weird. %)

Comment: @Vadzim I'm sorry, sir. I'm from China, I'm not good at English. so I maybe spend more time to answer a question  than you.